# How to disable checkbox for few records in Standard Data Table LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I am using standard datatable to display list of records along with checkbox for each record, i want to disable checkbox for few records. How to do using salesforce LWC

Comment: This is not supported in the standard data table component.

Comment: As Rahul mentioned it is not possible, You can try with custom buttons on it.
http://www.infallibletechie.com/2018/07/how-to-disable-and-enable-button-in.html

Answer (score 4):

While your requirement isn't directly possible with the standard LWC datatable, you could take one of the following alternate approaches. Option 1 would be the easiest alternative and implementing Option 2 is beyond the scope of this answer (*you could explore more, if interested*).

**Option 1:**

Using `selectedRows` attribute and `rowselection` event handler, clear out the checkbox immediately on a row (*if selection is not allowed for the particular row and the end user tries to select it*) and display a visual indication to the end user (*toast info or data table error*). Though this doesn't disable the checkbox at row level, it immediately clears it out and indicates the user not to select it.

Assuming that the datatable would display 5 rows [with row IDs: a, b, c, d, e] and the requirement is to restrict the user from selecting row with ID 'b' (in other words, checkbox on row b should have been disabled), your code should be similar as shown below. Note that you will have to tweak this code for your requirement.

In the HTML file, add the following to the datatable tag: `selected-rows={selectedRows} onrowselection={handleRowSelection}`

In the JS file, add a new field `selectedRows` and the following snippet.

```
handleSelectedRow(event) {
    // Clear the row selection checkbox if it is not allowed. 
    // Note that only the row ID needs to be passed to this array
    this.selectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows.map(row => {
            let rtnId;
            
            if(row.id !== 'b') // Implement your own code logic instead of this line
                rtnId = row.id;
            else{
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Info',
                        message: 'Row selection is not allowed', 
                        variant: 'info'
                    })
                );
            }
            
            return rtnId;
        });
    
    // Filter out the row that is not allowed for row selection
    event.detail.selectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows.filter(row => row.id !== 'b');
    // In the above filter function implement your own code logic
}
```

*If you don't want to show toast, you can use the standard data table error attribute to display indication at row level (but this would require that at least one of the columns is marked as editable).*

**Option 2:**

1. Build a custom datatable (that extends the standard data table) with custom data type (refer to section `Creating Custom Data Types` [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation)).
2. This custom data type should implement the checkbox and all the related row selection functionality.
3. Hide the standard checkbox column using the attribute `hide-checkbox-column`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement today and found a solution that doesn't need the custom datatable/custom Data types.
In the HTML datatable add the tag `selected-rows={selectedRows}`

Then in the JS have 2 different global variables for the process, one to store the selectedRows that the datatable is going to use, and one for the selectedRecords to use in another function.
In the handleRowSelection function do as such:

```
handleRowSelection(event) {
        this.selectedRecords=[];
        this.selectedRows=[];

        event.detail.selectedRows.forEach(row=>{
            if(row.canSelect){ //use your condition here
                //the datatable only needs the row id
                this.selectedRows=[...this.selectedRows, row.Id];
                //but to be able to acess the selected records you need to save them in a different variable
                this.selectedRecords.push(row);
                
            }
        });
    }
```

This will make users unable to select the rows with the canSelect atribute to false (you can substitute this for whatever condition needed in your case)